# "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service" Crawling with Apache Tika on a network folder

Tags: java, windows-server-2008-r2, apache-tika, unc

I am using a custom crawler that calls Apache Tika to extract text from different file formats up to 200M size in a Windows shared resource (using the file UNC). At some point after successfully crawling near 400k files, I start seeing this error with no stop in the logs:

> FileNotFoundException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete
>   the requested service

My code:

```
public String parseToString(String path, InputStream stream, int maxLength) throws IOException {
        WriteOutContentHandler handler =
                new WriteOutContentHandler(maxLength);
        try {
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
            context.set(Parser.class, super.getParser());
            super.getParser().parse(
                    stream, new BodyContentHandler(handler), new Metadata(), context);
        } catch (SAXException | TikaException e) {
            TextExtractor.logger.warning(
                    String.format("File processing Error in %s trying to get the text anyway: %s",
                            path, Utils.exceptionStacktraceToString(e.getCause())));
            return handler.toString();
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
        return handler.toString();
    }
```

Note: Running the crawler in the machine that stores the file locally will successfully process all files, small and large or wharever.

Using apache tika 1.13 and java 8.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace, by chance, so we can try to track down where in Tika this is causing problems?  How are you instantiating the InputStream -- if you change it to TikaInputStream.get(), does it work?

Comment: I am initializing the input stream by class loader, I will try your suggestion. I will update with the full stacktrace later today